# Using 3rd person "s" with relative pronouns

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, pronouns, syntax

My question is about adding S to the third person in questions starting by WH or any other type of word not only by do or does.

for instance, which of the following sentences are correct?

- Is there a national program that teach how to eat healthy?
- Is there a national program that teaches how to eat healthy?
- Who in your family is the person who eat most?
- Who in your family is the person who eats most?

Comment: Would you please show your effort first? Such as some relevant grammar rules you've already read.

Answer (score 2):

There's no special rule about adding an 's' for questions, it simply depends on the "person" of the verb, e.g.:

```
Singular                 Plural
1 I teach                we teach 
2 you teach              you teach
3 he, she, it teaches    they teach
```

If the the referent is singular, e.g. "a national program", use "teaches."
If the the referent is plural, e.g. "some programs", use "teach."

> Is there a **program** that **teaches** healthy eating habits?
>
> Are there **programs** that **teach** healthy eating habits?

Answer (score 0):

if the noun that the relative pronoun refers to is a singular countable noun then you should treat the relative pronoun as you would treat a singular countable noun. the same holds true for plural count nouns as well as uncount nouns.
So to answer your question:

> is there a national program that teaches how to eat healthy

would be correct since, that refers to a national program, which is a singular count noun, so the relative pronoun, That would be treated as if it were a singular count noun meaning that a singular verb should be used with it.

in the second example:

> who in your family is the person who eats most

would be correct.